# Key Events from USB Keyboard on Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, usb

I am writing an android app that needs to be able to detect **raw keyUp and keyDown events** from an **external USB keyboard**.

Does anybody know of a **good tutorial** for accomplishing this?

This is a first (intermediate) step in my eventual goal of communicating via a usb-to-serial connection to a stenotype machine.  Any additional information regarding collecting information over a usb-to-serial connection would also be helpful.